# Optimize query with IN clause for one-to-many association

Tags: sql, postgresql

Currently having 2 tables

1. Users -> *1 million records*
2. Requests -> *10 millions records*

A `User` has many `Requests`. I'm fetching all the users alongside with **their last created** `Request` with by something like the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN requests AS r
ON u.id = r.user_id
WHERE r.id IN (
    SELECT MAX(r.id)
    FROM users u
    INNER JOIN requests r ON r.user_id = u.id
    GROUP BY u.id
);
```

which does work, but with very very poor performance (> 7 sec). I understand the reason why and i'm trying to find a solution for that, even if i have to modify the schema.

**Note:** `Requests` table consists of `Boolean` columns, and I'm not quite sure if indexing will help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`distinct on ()` is one way to do this:

```
select distinct on (u.id) *
from users u
  join requests r on u.id = r.user_id
order by u.id, r.id desc;
```

Another option is a lateral join:

```
select *
from users u
  join lateral ( 
    select * 
    from requests r1 
    where u.id = r1.user_id
    order by id desc
    limit 1
  ) r on true
```

Comment: @I forgot to ask. Regarding the first way, is it possible to get the latest request?

Comment: @Makis: the first one you should return the latest per user.

Comment: The lateral option is working perfectly, and i was wondering if it makes any sense to have the last_request_date as a column on the users table? (because i was discussing this with some colleagues) Is this going to help the select queries? If yes, any sample would be very appreciated. If not then i will stick with the lateral join which is performing really good.